# Adding/removing summaries/plots requires re-compilation of runjags object

Tags: r, jags, runjags

Since runjags object with all plots is [too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837221/runjags-object-is-too-big), I tried to `run.jags` with `plot=FALSE`, save the resultant `runjags` object into file, restore it in new R session (as `out`) and then generate the plots by

```
out.with_summaries <- extend.jags(out, sample = 0, adapt = 0)
```

(for this trick see discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21859618/684229)

**However, for unknown reason this re-compiles and adapts the model again!** Even when I set the `sample = 0, adapt = 0`!

```
require(runjags)

t1 <- proc.time()
out.sum <- extend.jags(out, sample = 0, adapt = 0)
# Re-compiling rjags model and adapting...
# Calculating the Gelman-Rubin statistic for 4 variables....
# Convergence may have failed for this run for 4 parameters after 500
# iterations (multi-variate psrf = 214.873)
# Finished running the simulation
t2 <- proc.time()
print(t2 - t1)
#   user  system elapsed 
# 345.67    0.08  352.30
```

It takes a pretty long time just for plotting the graphs, which is pretty annoying. The same happens when I compute the runjags object *with* plots and then try to get rid of them to store the runjags object small:

```
t1 <- proc.time()
out.no_sum <- extend.jags(out.sum, sample = 0, adapt = 0, summarise=FALSE, plot=FALSE)
# Loading required package: rjags
# Loading required package: coda
# Loading required package: lattice
# Linked to JAGS 3.3.0
# Loaded modules: basemod,bugs
# Re-compiling rjags model and adapting...
# Finished running the simulation
t2 <- proc.time()
print(t2 - t1)
#    user  system elapsed 
#  327.53    0.05  329.73
```

#### Any tips on how to fix this issue (apart for writing my own plotting functions)?

**Warning:** The second run the `extend.jags` function on the same runjags object is already fast. But if you save the runjags object and load it again in a new session, `extend.jags` is slow again. It seems that `runjags` or JAGS are caching something (but not within the original runjags object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `extend.jags` function call is slow because the model is recompiling (in your case it is not actually adapting, despite the somewhat misleading message).  This is because you're using the rjags method from a saved object - this means the model has to be re-loaded into memory and made ready to sample from (even though you don't actually want to sample from it).  This doesn't happen the second time you call `extend.jags` because it is already compiled.

Using extend.jags in this way is really a bit of a hack - the next version of runjags will provide a cleaner way of doing this.  In the meantime, if you specify `adapt=0, sample=0, method='simple'` this *should* prevent the JAGS object being recompiled.

EDIT:  As stated in the help file for runjags, it is more efficient to recreate plots using `lattice::traceplot` or `densityplot` (or both).  To extract an MCMC object use `as.mcmc.list(runjags_object)` - this also allows you to extract specific variables if necessary, see ?as.mcmc.list.runjags